# Hydraulic analogy for electrical compounds

Tags: experimental-physics, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, applied-physics

I want a source (website or a book) where there are hydraulic simulation (or analogy) for all (or at least the most useful) electronic compounds?

Comment: What research have you done to answer your own question?

Answer (score 1):

*System Dynamics, A Unified Approach* by Karnopp and Rosenberg is a good starting point. The essential points of building a mechanical analogy are as follows, as described in detail in K&R:

First, the effort variable in an electrical circuit is *voltage* and its corresponding effort variable in a hydraulic system is *pressure*.

Second, the flow variable in an electrical circuit is *current* and its corresponding flow variable in a hydraulic system is *flow rate*.

Third, the lumped inertance element in an electrical circuit is *inductance* and its hydraulic analogy is *fluid mass*.

Fourth, the lumped compliance element in an electrical circuit is *capacitance* and its hydraulic analogy is an *air/fluid accumulator*.

Fifth, the effort source in an electrical system is a *voltage supply* and its hydraulic analogy is a *constant pressure pump*.

Sixth, the flow source in an electrical system is a *constant current supply* and its hydraulic analogy is a *positive displacement pump*.

Seventh, the transformation element in an electrical system is a *transformer* and its hydraulic analogy is a *two-piston ram*.

Eighth, the gyration element in an electrical system is a *DC motor* and I do not know of a hydraulic element that accepts a pressure as a causal input and outputs a flow rate in response.

Ninth, the lumped linear resistance element in an electrical system is an *ohmic resistor* and its hydraulic analogy is a *nonchoked orifice*.

Kirchhoff's laws for voltage and current are directly analogous.

Comment: I mean for example, a simulation of a bipolar transistor by a hydraulic current.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer; for [tag:resource-recommendation] questions (which seems to be the intent of this one) you need to add a bunch more details.

Comment: So, I saw many time a simulation of electric current by a water flow (the rate). So I want a source (book or website) which contain many electric compounds (capacitor, transistor, diode ... and more) explained by a flow of water which is more easy to understand than electric current.

Comment: You could probably come up with a servo valve that translates pressure to flow rate, but how does a DC motor do that?

Comment: The field strength of an electromagnet is proportional to the current flowing through the coil. The torque in a DC motor with electromagnets in it is proportional to the field strength they produce. therefore the torque is proportional to the current flow through the motor.